# How can I parse multiline records in Perl?

Tags: perl, parsing

I'm trying to parse the string that use delimiter '#'
this string has 3 lines

```
101#Introduction to the Professor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
head up to the Great Hall and speak to the professor to check in for class.#
#

102#Looking for Instructors#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
Look for the Battle Instructor.#
Talk to Battle Instructor#

103#Battle Instructor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
You have spoken to the Battle Instructor#
#
```

how to get each value before delimiter '#' so I can make a new format that look like this

```
[101] = {
    Title = "Introduction to the Professor",
    Description = {
        "head up to the Great Hall and speak to the professor to check in for class."
    },
    Summary = ""
},  
[102] = {
    Title = "Looking for Instructors",
    Description = {
        "Look for the Battle Instructor."
    },
    Summary = "Talk to Battle Instructor"
},
[103] = {
    Title = "Battle Instructor",
    Description = {
        "You have spoken to the Battle Instructor"
    },
    Summary = ""
},
```

Also there will be multiple data from 101 - n

I'm trying to use split with the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $data = '101#Introduction to the Professor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#';

my @values = split('#', $data);

foreach my $val (@values) {
    print "$val\n";
}

exit 0;
```

and the output:

```
101
Introduction to the Professor
SG_FEEL
QUE_NOIMAGE
```

How to read multiple line data? And also how to exclude some data, for example to match the new format, I don't need SG_FEEL and QUE_NOIMAGE data

Comment: What Perl code do you already have and how does it fail for you? Have you looked at [the split function]( http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html )? How does it not do what yu want?

Comment: Are those three line feeds really in your data? Also, could you please give a little more data (a sequence of 2 or 3 records instead of just 1)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. **Show us the code for your latest attempt** and where you got stuck. and explain why the result is not what you expected.  Edit your question to include the code, please don't add it in a comment, as it will probably be unreadable.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @ikegami I added the data records you ask for

Comment: Update the question field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl special variable `$/` sets the "input record separator"—the string that Perl uses to decide where a line ends. You can set that to something else.

```
use v5.26;
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;

$/ = "\n\n";  # set the input record separator

while( <DATA> ) {
    chomp;
    say "$. ------\n", $_;
    }

__END__
101#Introduction to the Professor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
head up to the Great Hall and speak to the professor to check in for class.#
#

102#Looking for Instructors#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
Look for the Battle Instructor.#
Talk to Battle Instructor#

103#Battle Instructor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
You have spoken to the Battle Instructor#
#
```

The output shows that you read whole records with each call to `<DATA>`:

```
1 ------
101#Introduction to the Professor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
head up to the Great Hall and speak to the professor to check in for class.#
#
2 ------
102#Looking for Instructors#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
Look for the Battle Instructor.#
Talk to Battle Instructor#
3 ------
103#Battle Instructor#SG_FEEL#QUE_NOIMAGE#
You have spoken to the Battle Instructor#
#
```

From there you can parse that record however you need.

Answer (score 0):

Reading multiple lines is easy, see [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html):

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename
    or die "Couldn't read '$filename': $!";
my @input = <$fh>;
```

Now you want to go through all lines and look at what to do with them:

```
my $linenumber;
my %info; # We want to collect information
while ($linenumber < $#input) {
```

Each line that starts with `nnn#` starts a new item:

```
    if( $input[ $linenumber ] =~ /^(\d+)#/ ) {
        my @data = split /#/, $input[ $linenumber ];
        $info{ number } = $data[0];
        $info{ Title } = $data[1];
        $linenumber++;
    };
```

Now, read stuff into the description until we encounter an empty line:

```
    while ($input[$linenumber] !~ /^#$/) {
        $info{ Description } .= $input[$linenumber];
        $linenumber++;
    };

    $linenumber++; # skip the last "#" line
```

Now, output the stuff in `%info`, formatting left as an exercise. I've used `qq{}` for demonstration purposes. You will want to change that to `qq()`:

```
    print qq{Number: "$info{ number }"\n};
    print qq{Title: "$info{ Title }"\n};
    print qq(Description: {"$info{ Description }"}\n);
};
```

Comment: thank you for explaining so detail, definitely will try it